# MongoDB full-text search on objects

Tags: mongodb, full-text-search

I have documents looking like this:

```
> db.productGroup.find()
{
  "_id": "1",
  "groupName": {
    "de": "ein produkt",
    "en": "a product"
  },
  "ownerUuid": "companyA"
}
{
  "_id": "2",
  "groupName": {
    "de": "ein anderes produkt",
    "en": "another product"
  },
  "ownerUuid": "companyA"
}
{
  "_id": "3",
  "groupName": {
    "de": "ein produkt",
    "en": "a product"
  },
  "ownerUuid": "companyB"
}
```

And I have the following index configuration:

```
> db.productGroup.getIndexes()
[
  {
    "v": 1,
    "key": {
      "_id": 1
    },
    "name": "_id_",
    "ns": "junit_masterdata.productGroup"
  },
  {
    "v": 1,
    "key": {
      "_fts": "text",
      "_ftsx": 1
    },
    "name": "groupName_text",
    "ns": "junit_masterdata.productGroup",
    "weights": {
      "groupName": 1
    },
    "default_language": "english",
    "language_override": "language",
    "textIndexVersion": 2
  },
  {
    "v": 1,
    "key": {
      "groupId": 1
    },
    "name": "groupId_1",
    "ns": "junit_masterdata.productGroup"
  }
]
```

Now I'd like to use the full-text search. However, nothing is found:

```
> db.productGroup.find({ $text: { $search: "produkt" } })
Fetched 0 record(s) in 0ms
> db.productGroup.find({ $text: { $search: "ein" } })
Fetched 0 record(s) in 0ms
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Bonus points if I can split up the search by language, but this is only a nice to have at the moment.

PS: Index, documents, and query are being generated in Java (Morphia), but I don't even get it to run on the shell.

Comment: You cannot do that. You need to directly specify a field ( i.e `groupName.de` ) in the defined index in order to search that field. You can optionally include multiple fields directly `{ "groupName.en": "text", "groupName.en": "text" }` in the definition, but it's really not going to be valid since you can only specify one language per index and only one text index per collection. Also if you intend a german language search then you need to define that as the default language on the index as well. Mongo text indexing is not a full blown product, just a "lite" implementation for basic needs.

Comment: Also things like "ein" should be ignored in a language search just as "a" would be. Only things like "product" and "product" would be returned, just as "products" would be a valid match as a plural.

Comment: Thanks for the quick feedback. I guess we'll need to go for the full blown thing then: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/specify-language-for-text-index/

Comment: Other products seem more suited to what you want, if indeed you need to be able to search for data in multiple languages. Many databases whose purpose is not directly focused on text search offer a facilty to implement text searching, however none of them provide the features which real purpose built text search engines are designed to do.

Comment: The features are fine for our use case (full-text search with German and English for the correct stop-word + stemming). Our main concern is, if we should really put that workload into the regular database.